# CSS Parallax behaving strangely, background is being cut off

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup CSS Parallax on this website, however we can't change the general structure of it much at all.

Here is a [link to the website](http://devsite104.clickserver.co.uk/) where you can see the issue on the FINANCE SPECIALISTS panel. It works fine apart from the background being cut off, seems to be just the height of the panel however it should be much taller so you can't see the top as you scroll down.

Brief overview of my code:

```css
html {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  &__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    &--base {
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }
    &--back {
      transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    }
  }
}

body {
  font-family: @alpha-font;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: @secondary-colour;
  color: @text-colour;
  .parallax;
}

.row-block.finance {
  padding: 75px 0;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  .parallax__layer--back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    background: url('@{dealer-img}/theme/finance-bk.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .container {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Homepage Search Finance -->
<div class="{v2_4_MOBILE_ON_OFF} {v2_4_TABLET_ON_OFF} {v2_4_DESKTOP_ON_OFF}">
  <div class="row-block finance parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer--back parallax__layer"></div>
    <div class="parallax__layer--base parallax__layer" id="budget-search-thirds">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sixcol"></div>
        <div class="sixcol last">
          <h2><span class="preHeading">Used Car</span>Finance Specialists</h2>
          <p class="right">We have relationships with high street lenders and specialist motoring finance houses too, that is why <strong>we have helped hundreds of customers</strong> secure the <strong>best finance deal</strong> for their budget.</p>
          <div class="fin-slider">
            <div id="finance-budget-range-min" class="clear-fix">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="budget-slider">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="amount-budget-range-min">Monthly Budget:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="amount-budget-range-min" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="slider-group">
                    <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search-btn">
                  <a id="button-budget-range-min" class="button" href="/search_page.php?budget=200" title="budget search">Search</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- // Homepage Search Finance -->
```

Comment: Increase the height of this class `.row-block.finance` currently it is set to `320px` the background position center is causing the image to crop

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. It just adds white space below the content. The parallax background should look like so: http://www.martynleeball.com/mps